# angular.toJson($scope.object) and JSON.stringify($scope.object) return NULL

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, http

So I tried to run angular.toJson on two different objects. They're both arrays.

The difference however is that one is hardcoded and the other is returned by an $http call. When I run angular.toJson on the hardcoded array, it returns what I expect it to return; a string version of my array that can be passed as a JSON object to a restful API function. However when I run angular.toJson on the array returned by an $http call, it returns NULL.

The array from both

So in the HTML file:

Suppose:

```
$scope.hardCodedArray = [{
    item1 : "",
    item2 : "",
    item3 : "",
}, {
    item1 : "",
    item2 : "",
    item3 : "",
}];
```

and

```
http.get("SOMEURL").success(function (response) {$scope.httpReturnedArray = response.ARRAY;});
```

where the information at SOMEURL is:

```
{"ARRAY":[{
    item1 : "",
    item2 : "",
    item3 : "",
}, {
    item1 : "",
    item2 : "",
    item3 : "",
}]}
```

And the kicker here is that {{hardCodedArray}} and {{httpReturnedArray}} both return the same thing when printed out on in index.html. So my problem here is that:

```
{{ angular.toJson($scope.hardCodedArray) }}
```

returns the string of the array as expected.

BUT!

```
{{ angular.toJson($scope.httpReturnedArray) }}
```

returns null.

Why is that? Any help would be greatly greatly appreciated. Thank you so much!

Comment: where is `$scope.httpReturnedArray` defined? Not shown in your code. You are overwriting the `hardcodedarray` instead in the callback

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/Angular.js#L1145".It measns your $scope.httpReturnedArray is undefined  Check what the valuew of $scope.httpReturnedArray .

Comment: I wrote the wrong code in the question. It was originally actually

http.get("SOMEURL").success(function (response) {$scope.httpReturnedArray = response.ARRAY;});

Comment: create a demo that replicates this problem. There is not enough code context provided for us to reproduce this

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you don't have a valid json.

The next thing I would say is that it appears you could be incorrectly referencing the ARRAY object in your response. If the code is directly pulled from your project, there are case changes in your object names. ie: $scope.hardcodedarray & $scope.hardCodedArray.

You may want to check for the same thing happening with $scope.httpReturnedArray.

The best thing you can do to debug this is to add a

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(response);
```

to your success function to see exactly what, if anything, is being returned.

Comment: Another question I would have for you is when and where you are trying to view the value of $scope.httpReturnedArray. It is possible that the $http call has not completed before you are trying to get the value from it. Have you attempted to check the value of it within the success function?

Comment: both hardCodedArray and httpReturnedArray give the same thing when printed out in the index.html. The problem arises when they're both stringified: one the first returns what I expect but the second returns Null

Edit: Yes the http call has completed when I try to call it and it still fails. I print out both {{httpReturnedArray}} and {{angular.toJson(httpReturnedArray)}}. The former returns what I expect, the latter returns Null.